# Problema al redireccionar CSS

Tags: java, jsp

Tengo una situación. Tengo un formulario clientes en JSP con el nombre 'agregar_clientes.jsp' que lo que hace es guardar datos en el BD. Todo funciona muy bien, y al guardar los datos deseo que la página lo redireccione a "tabla_clientes.jsp" que contiene la tabla de los registros. Todo bien; pero el problema que tengo es que una vez redireccionado, la página "tabla_clientes.jsp" me aparece sin los CSS (sin el estilo css). Todas las páginas que tengo se abren si problemas de manera manual, pero al redireccionarlo se pierden todos los estilos. Lo que utilizo para redireccionar es un servlet.

```
if (request.getParameter("btn_insertar") != null) {
  //Boton insertar 
  cli.setRuc(request.getParameter("txt_ruc"));
  cli.setRazon_social(request.getParameter("txt_razon"));
  cli.setSexo(request.getParameter("cbo_sexo").toString());
  cli.setCompania(request.getParameter("txt_compania"));
  cli.setDomicilio(request.getParameter("txt_domicilio"));
  cli.setCiudad(request.getParameter("cbo_ciudad").toString());
  cli.setBarrio(request.getParameter("cbo_barrio").toString());
  cli.setTelefono_fijo(request.getParameter("txt_tel_fijo"));
  respuesta = evento.insertar(cli);
  rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("vista/clientes/tabla_clientes.jsp");
}
```

Como dije, la url es correcto; el problema es que se pierden los estilos :(

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Puedes hacer diferentes cosas: 1. Agregar la referencia al CSS en cada JSP que utilices. o 2. Utilizar templates para que desde un solo template se inserte el CSS para todo el proyecto. la más simple es la nro 1.